# Clear the jquery dialog content on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

When i click on a link in my page, i am opening a jquery dialog box (if it is not already open) and adding a jquery ui tab inside it. Followed example from **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/AeXNP/30/)**

But when i close my jquery dialog and reopen it, the tabs which were opened previously are showing up. I would like to have no tabs inside the jquery dialog, when i close and reopen the dialog, so that i can add a new tab inside the dialog.

**This is the code that is present in my jquery document ready:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tab_counter = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
var $tabs_example_1 = $('#example_1').tabs();

$('#addUiTab').click(function(){
        var label = 'Tab'+tab_counter,
        content = '<span id="tab">This is a sample tab content</span>';

        $('body').append('<div id="tab_'+tab_counter+'">'+content+'</div>');
        $tabs_example_1.tabs('add','#tab_'+tab_counter,label);
        tab_counter++;

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**This is my function that opens a dialog box (if it is not already open) and adds a tab inside it, when i click on a link in my page:**

```
function open_dialog()
{
    if(($("#jdialog_box_content").dialog( "isOpen" ) === true) == false)
    {
        $('#jdialog_box_content').dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) {  },
        close: function(event, ui) {  },
        autoResize: false,
        width: 460,
        height: 230,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        title: 'Dialog1'
        });
    }

    $('#addUiTab').trigger("click");
}
```

**And finally this is the html that is used for the jquery tabs, inside jquery dialog box:**

```
<div id="jdialog_box_content" style="display:none;">    
    <div id="example_1" class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1-2">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2-2">This is tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3-2">This is tab number 3</a></li>           
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1-2">Tab 1<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div id="tabs-2-2">This is tab 2<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div id="tabs-3-2">This is tab 3<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am just curious to know how can i remove the existing tabs in my jquery dialog box, when it is reopened.

**Note:** I am following the [example at this site](http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jst/#examples) for jquery ui tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `close: function(event, ui) { $("#jdialog_box_content").html(""); }` in your dialog declaration.
if you don't need empty dialog and just no tabs you can do so by that:

```
$('#jdialog_box_content').dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) {  },
        close: function(event, ui) {
            var $tabs = $('#example_1');
            var l = $tabs.tabs('length');
            while(l)
            {
               $tabs.tabs('remove', l-1);                       
               l = $tabs.tabs('length');
            }

        },
        autoResize: false,
        width: 460,
        height: 230,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        title: 'Dialog1'
        });
```

Comment: Using the above option, when i reopen the dialog box, there were no tabs inside it... it was just empty.

Comment: Hi this will work, but there are known errors with IE (up to version 9) when setting html. A better way would be to call `$("#jdialog_box_content").empty();` this will keep the DOM correctly up to date, without breaking any references to dom elements inside the the dialog, no matter what browser you're running.

Comment: I even tried: $("#jdialog_box_content").empty(); in the close event of the dialog box. But the dialog box is still empty on reopening it.

Comment: @dskanth I thought that is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i could also use a for loop code under the close event of the jquery dialog, to close all the open tabs:

```
close: function(event, ui) 
{ 
    for (var i = $('#example_1').tabs('length') - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $('#example_1').tabs('remove', i);                  
    }
}
```